# How to create transparent button using gtk in c

Tags: c, gtk

I want to add transparent button in my application and i am using gtk. How to do it?
I am using `gtk_color_button_set_alpha()`:

```
gtk_color_button_set_alpha(GtkColorButton *button, guint16 100);
```

But it is giving error as

> error: expected expression before ‘GtkColorButton’
>   error: too few arguments to function ‘gtk_color_button_set_alpha’

Comment: Can you post your actual invocation of `gtk_color_button_set_alpha()`? I assume that is not `gtk_color_button_set_alpha(GtkColorButton *button, guint16 100);` since that should not compile.

Comment: GtkColorButton is a widget for the user to pick a color. gtk_color_button_set_alpha() will just set the opacity value of the currently selected color, it will not affect the opacity of the button itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a fairly recent GTK+ (3.8) this should be quite easy: See [opacity property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--opacity) and `gtk_widget_set_opacity()`. Note that this depends on display manager features and you cannot rely on the opacity working everywhere. You can check if it works though: `gtk_widget_is_composited()` should tell you that.